# ¿Cómo evaluó si una palabra se repite en un frase?

Tags: java

necesito un método que evalué cuantas veces se repite un palabra en una frase tengo el siguiente método, pero al ejecutarlo me da error alguien sabe por que, y como podría solucionarlo?

```
      public class Contador {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
       String frase,Palabra;
        System.out.println("Escribe una frase: ");
        frase = sc.next();
        System.out.println("¿Que palabra quieres saber si se repitio?:");
        Palabra = sc.next();
        System.out.println(identificarPalabra(frase, Palabra));
       }

       private static void identificarPalabra(String frase, String Palabra) {
        String[] prueba = frase.split(" ");
        
        for(int i = 0; i< prueba.length;i++) {
            String prueba2 = String.valueOf(prueba[i]);
            if(prueba2.equals(Palabra)) {
                System.out.println("El Valor " + prueba[i] +" se repitio : " + i +" veces");
            }
        }
        
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es simple compañero, `next()` te trae el texto hasta que consiga un espacio, por ejemplo, si tienes un texto como `Hola amigo`, `next()` traera `Hola`, lo que deberías usar es `nextLine()`, ademas lo que tienes abajo es un metodo `void` no retorna nada por lo que tratar de mostrarlo dentro de un `System.out.println` esta errado.

Tendrías que tener algo así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
   String frase,Palabra;
    System.out.println("Escribe una frase: ");
    frase = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("¿Que palabra quieres saber si se repitio?:");
    Palabra = sc.nextLine();
    identificarPalabra(frase, Palabra);
}

private static void identificarPalabra(String frase, String Palabra) {
    String[] prueba = frase.split(" ");
    
    for(int i = 0; i< prueba.length;i++) {
        String prueba2 = String.valueOf(prueba[i]);
        if(prueba2.equals(Palabra)) {
            System.out.println("El Valor " + prueba[i] +" se repitio : " + i +" veces");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Eres un crack, gracias por tu respuesta.